# Visualforce Gray Border Lightning Community

Tags: visualforce, community, css

I tried to hold off posting because I feel like this is just ridiculous, but I'm so frustrated I have no choice. I've got a simple solid color box to drop on a lightning community, keeps showing this gray border. I've tried a css selector, but the only one I'm finding is .oneAlohaPageDeprecated.content, and modifying that does not seem to do anything. I've tried modifying the VF page with:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="false">
```

```
 <style type="text/css">
             body {
  background: #FFFECC !important;
}
      </style>
```

Nothing seems to work. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Has anyone managed to solve this problem?